# inner join query in update statement giving error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE secugconductorinfo
       INNER JOIN tblsecugconductor
               ON secugconductorinfo.CONDUCTORGUID = tblsecugconductor.globalid
SET    secugconductorinfo.conductorcount = '0'
WHERE  Upper(tblsecugconductor.FILE_NAME) LIKE '%Q1222_S%'
       AND secugconductorinfo.conductorsize = 'Unknown'
       AND secugconductorinfo.insulation = 'Unknown'
       AND secugconductorinfo.material = 'Unknown'
       AND secugconductorinfo.conductorcount = '1'
```

I want to update `conductorcount=0` for all rows of secugconductorinfo based on the join with tblsecugconductor.
But I'm getting:

> Error report: 
>   SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword 00971. 00000 - "missing SET keyword"

How should I change my query to perform this update?

Comment: What's the error? And what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Whats the exact error?

Comment: We'll need some more information to help you. Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish with this query, and what is happening instead. If you get an error message, please show it. You can edit your post using the "edit" link above. Good luck!

Comment: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

Comment: i wana update conductorcount=0 for all rows of secugconductorinfo based on join with tblsecugconductor

Comment: I'm not sure you can update a join. But if I get it right you only want to update 1 of the tables. You may have to move the join to the WHERE condition. If you do that, consider testing your query against a few edge cases, to make sure it works as intended.

Comment: I've edited your comments into the code. If you disagree with this edit, you can roll it back by clicking on the "edited ... ago", which will give you a menu where you can roll it back. I hope my edits will help you get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE secugconductorinfo
SET    secugconductorinfo.conductorcount = '0'
WHERE  secugconductorinfo.conductorsize = 'Unknown'
       AND secugconductorinfo.insulation = 'Unknown'
       AND secugconductorinfo.material = 'Unknown'
       AND secugconductorinfo.conductorcount = '1' 
AND exists (select 1
            from tblsecugconductor
            where secugconductorinfo.CONDUCTORGUID = tblsecugconductor.globalid
              and Upper(tblsecugconductor.FILE_NAME) LIKE '%Q1222_S%')
```

You should use an exists statement to make the join. I corrected your code above.

Answer (score -1):

try this one :

```
UPDATE secugconductorinfo
SET conductorcount ='0'
from secugconductorinfo aa
INNER JOIN tblsecugconductor bb
       ON aa.CONDUCTORGUID = 
              bb.globalid

 WHERE  Upper(bb.FILE_NAME) 
                LIKE '%Q1222_S%'
  AND aa.conductorsize = 'Unknown'
  AND aa.insulation = 'Unknown'
  AND aa.material = 'Unknown'
  AND aa.conductorcount = '1'
```